# How do I print an exposed filter block in a template file?

Tags: 8, views, theming

I have a view with an exposed taxonomy filter. I configured it to be displayed as a separate block so that I can print it another twig template. I tried this.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_block() for block.html.twig.
 */
 function themename_preprocess_block(array &$variables) {
   $variables['featured'] = views_embed_view('view_name', 'contextual_filter_block_machine_name');
 }
```

Then I used `{{ featured }}` in the  block template, but it doesn't work.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Did you rename `themename` to be your theme's machine name? Also, can you run a `debug(json_encode(views_embed_view('view_name', 'contextual_filter_block_machine_name')))` and then check the "Recent Log Reports" page?

Answer (score 0):

I used another approach to solve the problem. I overrode the views template to print the exposed filter where I wanted. You can get it as

```
{{ exposed}}
```

in the twig template.

Answer (score 0):

I almost always use the `twig_tweak` module, there is 3 ways to render a block.
You can see the doc here [Twig tweak Block render](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/twig-tweak-2x/cheat-sheet#s-drupal-block), you should probably use

```
drush ev "print_r(array_keys(\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block')->getDefinitions()));"
```

find your block in the list and then use

```
{{ drupal_block('your_block_id') }}
```